# Pass values of tuple as prarameters to proc

Tags: tuples, nim-lang

I have a proc called:

`proc fill(image: Pixels, r, g, b, a: uint8`
which needs 4 uint8 values passed to it as parameters to fill a image with a color.

I also have a tuple called green:
`let green = (0.uint8, 255.uint8, 0.uint8, 255.uint8)`

I wish i could call the proc like this, or similar: `image.fill(green)` but that errors with a type mismatch.
Is there a more elegant way than writing `ìmage.fill(green[0], green[1], green[2], green[3])`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the simplest approach would be to wrap the `fill()` function in another function that takes a tuple argument. Something like this would work, overloading `fill()` to take the new argument types, so long as the return types of `fill()` and the overloaded `fill()` match:

```
proc fill(image: Pixels, color: tuple[r, g, b, a: uint8]): void =
  fill(image, color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a)
```

Then calling `fill()` with the tuple argument will call the appropriate version:

```
myImage.fill(green)
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I was stuck with something like `proc f(tuple[x:int, y:int])`, forgetting that I needed to name the (single) functional argument despite unpacking its members. `proc f(_: tuple[x:int, y:int])` works.

Answer (score 2):

If you routinely want to perform this kind of tuple unpacking (like `f(*a)` in python / `apply` in lisp(s)), you can write some macros for this unpacking (and currying since you have arguments not present in the tuple required for `fill`).

**unpacking / spread / apply:**

```
macro `..*`(f, t: typed): auto =
    var args: seq[NimNode] = @[]
    let ty = t.getTypeImpl
    for e in ty:
        args.add(newDotExpr(t, e[0]))
    result = newCall(f, args)
```

To give you the unpacking; however, you will also need a `curry` for doing the equivelent of `functools.partial` in python (for the first argument `image`)

**Currying:**

```
macro curry(f: typed; args: varargs[untyped]): untyped =
    let ty = f.getType
    let tyi = f.getTypeImpl[0]
    assert($ty[0] == "proc", "first param is not a function")
    let n_remaining = ty.len - 2 - args.len
    assert n_remaining > 0, "cannot curry all the parameters"
    var callExpr = newCall(f)
    args.copyChildrenTo callExpr
    var params: seq[NimNode] = @[]
    params.add ty[1]
    for i in 0..<n_remaining:
        let loc = i+2+args.len
        let name = $(tyi[loc - 1][0])
        let param = ident(name)
        params.add newIdentDefs(param, ty[loc])
        callExpr.add param
    result = newProc(procType = nnkLambda, params = params, body = callExpr)
```

```
proc baz(o: string, r, g, b, a: uint8): string = $g
let green: tuple[r, g, b, a: uint8] = (0.uint8, 255.uint8, 0.uint8, 0.uint8)
echo (baz.curry("example") ..* green)
```

---

I do not think you can make a macro that works *on the tuple itself rather than both `fill` (or the function) and the tuple both* because macros can not go this direction "up" in the AST.